# VBA convert to numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro and it was working perfectly. I tried to implement it in my VBA and for some reason it is not working, I mean it is working but I have to double click on the cells to be successful.
Please be aware I am new at VBA I try to make my job easier by using VBA. What I have to do is :
convert to numbers and decrease decimals to two.

```
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

So here is what I used, and I am not sure what is wrong.
Anyone can give me advice ?

Comment: I recommend reading [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913882/16578424) - if you apply those adivses your issue might be fixed.

Comment: Are the numbers you are trying to transform recognized as numeric values or are they recognized as string (text) values?

Comment: They are recognised as string.

Comment: Why are they recognised as strings? Are they simply formatted as string or are they in format different from your native number format?

Comment: I am not sure I can follow. When I import the file from csv. it is importing as text and I need to convert this to numbers to be able to write a report.

Comment: @AlmaJelena Please edit your question to provide a sample of the csv data that reproduces your problem, along with the method you are using to import the file. If I create a csv file with text strings for numbers, the strings get converted to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro. It only converts numbers formatted as string to real numbers.

```
Sub ConvertToNumbers()
    With Range("C2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
End Sub
```